# How do I add the page number to the page title on drupal default paginated pages?

Tags: paging

It has been recommended by an SEO consultant that for paginated pages the page number is included in the page title to avoid duplicated content. How do I achieve this?

I did this:

```
    function hook_pager_link($variables){
  $text = $variables['text'];
  $page_new = $variables['page_new'];
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $parameters = $variables['parameters'];
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];

  $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '';
  if ($new_page = implode(',', pager_load_array($page_new[$element], $element, explode(',', $page)))) {
    $parameters['page'] = $new_page;
  }

  $query = array();
  if (count($parameters)) {
    $query = drupal_get_query_parameters($parameters, array());
  }
  if ($query_pager = pager_get_query_parameters()) {
    $query = array_merge($query, $query_pager);
  }

  // Set each pager link title
  if (!isset($attributes['title'])) {
    static $titles = NULL;
    if (!isset($titles)) {
      $titles = array(
        t('« first') => t('Go to first page'),
        t('‹ previous') => t('Go to previous page'),
        t('next ›') => t('Go to next page'),
        t('last »') => t('Go to last page'),
      );
    }
    if (isset($titles[$text])) {
      $attributes['title'] = $titles[$text];
    }
    elseif (is_numeric($text)) {
      $attributes['title'] = t('Go to page @number', array('@number' => $text));
    }
  }

  // @todo l() cannot be used here, since it adds an 'active' class based on the
  //   path only (which is always the current path for pager links). Apparently,
  //   none of the pager links is active at any time - but it should still be
  //   possible to use l() here.
  // @see http://drupal.org/node/1410574

  //put the pagination page number into the title tag
  $attributes['href'] = url($_GET['q'], array('query' => $query));
  //add page
  $page = t('page');
  $pattern = '/' . $page . ' \d/';
  $title = drupal_get_title();
  preg_match($pattern, $title, $matches);
  if(!$matches){
    $new_title = $title . ' - ' .  t('page') . ' ' . ($page + 1);
    drupal_set_title($new_title);
    }
  return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . check_plain($text) . '</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you investigated the [Page Title](https://drupal.org/project/page_title) module? It, among other things, features

> **Pagination Suffix**: One of the things you may noticed about Drupal in terms of SEO is that whenever you go through a paged list of content, the page title never changes. Google Webmaster Tools will flag this up as a problem as you essentially have several different pages all being identified with the same page title. A new feature, introduced in Page Title 2.1, is the ability to append the page number as a suffix pattern. This means any URL which contains something like page=2 in the query string will also have an optional token pattern suffixed onto the end of it. Important: for this feature to work properly, you need to be running Token 1.12 or later.

Comment: This would be very useful I would imagine.

Comment: The mentioned module is not used anymore... Use https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Comment: Just use something like [current-page:title] [current-page:page-number] | [site:name]

Answer (score 1):

If you have to set other tags or configration related to SEO I suggest you [Metatag](https://drupal.org/project/metatag) module, that helps also with page title.

Comment: Curious to know how I would avoid the number to show up on the first page.

Comment: In this case you could alter the metatag using hooks in a module or in your theme